# Renaming files by removing delimited substring

Tags: shell-script, files, scripting, rename, mv

I have a lot of folders and subfolders with files with name `1. Introduction--- [ FreeCourseWeb.com ] ---.mp4` I want to rename all files recursively (folders and subfolders) to just `1. Introduction.mp4` suppressing the substring `--- [ FreeCourseWeb.com ] ---`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to rename all the files that has a digit at the start of their name, contains the substring `---` twice, immediately followed by `.mp4` at the very end of the name.  Furthermore assuming you want to remove the bit between the two `---` substrings including these substrings themselves:

```
find . -type f -name '[[:digit:]]*---*---.mp4' -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        mv -i "$pathname" "${pathname%---*---.mp4}.mp4"
    done' sh {} +
```

This finds all the regular file with names matching the given pattern, in or below the current directory, and then removes the suffix string matching `---*---.mp4` and adds the `.mp4` suffix back on.

Without using `find` (in `bash`):

```bash
shopt -s globstar nullglob dotglob

for pathname in ./**/[[:digit:]]*---*---.mp4; do
    [[ ! -f $pathname ]] && continue
    mv -i "$pathname" "${pathname%---*---.mp4}.mp4"
done
```

This is essentially the same as the `find` command, but will also rename symbolic links.  The three shell options that are set at the start enables the `**` globbing pattern used for matching recursively down into subdirectories (`globstar`), makes sure that non-matching patterns are deleted rather than kept unexpanded (`nullglob`), and makes sure that globbing patterns match hidden names (`dotglob`).

In the `zsh` shell:

```sh
for pathname in ./**/[[:digit:]]*---*---.mp4(.ND); do
    mv -i $pathname ${pathname%---*---.mp4}.mp4
done
```

Here, the dot in the glob qualifier `(.ND)` makes the preceding pattern only match regular files, while `N` and `D` acts like enabling `nullglob` and `dotglob` in `bash`, but only for this specific pattern.

Comment: Thank you very much !!!! Works like a charm for me. Congrats

Answer (score 0):

Using the `rename` tool of the `util-linux` package (sometimes referred to as `rename.ul`) and `find`:

```
find . -type f -name '*--- \[ FreeCourseWeb.com \] ---.mp4'\
  -exec rename -i -- '--- [ FreeCourseWeb.com ] ---' '' {} \;
```

Option `-i` asks for permission to overwrite existing files.

---

Using Larry Wall's Perl `rename` script and `find`:

```
find . -type f -name '*--- \[ FreeCourseWeb.com \] ---.mp4'\
  -exec rename 's/--- \[ FreeCourseWeb.com \] ---//' {} \;
```

Existing files are not overwritten per default unless the `-f` / `--force` option is used. You will see an error message `... already exists` instead.

Comment: Gives me 2 errors : -i doesn't exist and find: paths must precede expression: `rename'